# Join multiple columns to another table to return description from number

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables in a join select. One of the tables is a list of reviews of a 'thing' that a user has done. They basically give it a number of stars. 1 to 5.

two main tables:

**places**

```
id    INT
name  VARCHAR(128)
```

**reviews**

```
review_id    INT
welcome      INT
hospitality  INT
condition    INT
```

example query:

```
select p.name, r.welcome, r.hospitality, r.condition from places p
join reviews r on p.id = r.review_id

name  nameA
welcome  1
hospitality  3
condition  4
```

I have a separate table (review_descriptors) which contains the descriptors for the number of stars given e.g.

```
1: bad
2: ok
3: good
4: very good
5: excellent
```

So a typical row from the first query, with all the joins could be:

```
name   welcome   hospitality   condition
nameA  1         3             4
```

But what I would like the returned data to be is:

```
name   welcome   hospitality   condition
nameA  bad       good          very good
```

descriptor table

```
review_num   INT // this will match against the value of welcome, hospitality, condition
description  VARCHAR(32)
```

I don't think I can simply join as its multiple fields per row

Also, I'd rather not parse the data on the way in to the table in case I want to globally change the review descriptors later

Is there a way to do this? It's almost like a reverse look up I guess based on the main query reults

Comment: you can do multiple joins.. try this and if fails, post your ddl ( with field names )

Comment: How does the first query produce multiple *columns*?

Comment: Updated question with more information

Comment: What happens if decor and ambience get added to the reviewing criteria?

Comment: Great question @Strawberry - I want to try build for this but it looks like I'll have to manage the queries which is not ideal

Comment: So normalise your schema. Eg.:`(review_id*, review_category_id*,score)` where `*` = (component of) PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your data structure, then conditional aggregation would do what you want?

```
select p.name,
       max(case when r.name = 'welcome' then d.description end) as welcome,
       max(case when r.name = 'hospitality' then d.description end) as hospitality,
       max(case when r.name = 'condition' then d.description end) as condition,
from places p join
     reviews r 
     on p.id = r.id join
     review_descriptors d
     on r.numstars = d.numstars
group by p.name;
```

EDIT:

On the other hand, if the results are already pivoted, you need multiple joins:

```
select p.*, dw.description as welcome, dh.descrption as hospitality,
       dc.condition as condition
from places p join
     reviews r 
     on p.id = r.id left join
     review_descriptors dw
     on r.welcome = dw.numstars lef tjoin
     review_descriptors dh
     on r.hospitality = dh.numstars lef tjoin
     review_descriptors dc
     on r.condition = dc.numstars
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple joins on review_descriptors, using aliases, for example something like that :

```
select
    places.name,
    welcome_descriptor.description AS welcome,
    hospitality_descriptor.description AS hospitality,
    condition_descriptor.description AS condition

    from places
        inner join reviews on reviews.review_id = places.id
        inner join review_descriptors AS welcome_descriptor on welcome_descriptor.review_num = reviews.welcome
        inner join review_descriptors AS hospitality_descriptor on hospitality_descriptor.review_num = reviews.hospitality
        inner join review_descriptors AS condition_descriptor on condition_descriptor.review_num = reviews.condition
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    places.`name`,
    wdes.description AS welcome,
    hdes.description AS hospitality,
    cdes.description AS `condition`
FROM
reviews
INNER JOIN places ON reviews.review_id = places.id
LEFT JOIN review_descriptors AS wdes ON reviews.welcome = wdes.review_num
LEFT JOIN review_descriptors AS hdes ON reviews.hospitality = hdes.review_num
LEFT JOIN review_descriptors AS cdes ON reviews.`condition` = cdes.review_num
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad635c/1/0